# system access with ipv6 from anywhere

Tags: ipv6, remote-access

I recently got an ipv6 address to my device and also have another ipv6 to another user who is in different location. my question is how can I connect to his computer running Linux or windows with ipv6.

please help me

Comment: If all the basics of IPv6 support (addressing, routing, and DNS) are set up correctly for your device and for the remote device you'll be connecting to, then connecting to its fully qualified host name (like OtherUsersDevice.example.com) should just work. If it doesn't just work, you'll need to tell is what protocol/app you want to use, what you tried so far, and exactly what result you got when you tried.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i never used any app except team viewer. i heard that with ipv6 we can connect to anyone.. ipv6 is properly configured on both the devices. it clearly shows ipv6 when i do an ipconfig and also on a google search and also on a linux machine. please suggest some app or steps so that i can connect laptop and also desktop .

Answer (score 1):

In the same way as you did it via ipv4 by using UDP/TCP-sockets. The game is still the same, DNS, ip, tcp/udp-port. SSH, remote desktop- when using names within the URL you won't see a difference. 
Of course, on wire you will see the new addresses and the AAAA-records.

Comment: can you please help me clearly with details steps or a place where the information is shown.. iam new to this type of work.. help required ..thanks

Comment: It depends on it what you want. Your question was very general. O course you should have IPv6-connectivity. You may have DNS-records(AAAA and PTR) otherwise you should use the IPs directly - sometimes in brackets []. You should read network tutorials - IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: For simple connection between tow linux boxes start sshd on one site and use **ssh user@2001:db8::1** on the other site. Or **vncserver** at one site and **vncviewer [2001:db8::1]:1** on the other.